# Proper Client <-> Server Communication

Tags: c#, server, client, client-server, communication

Let's say I have a client and a server for a simple chatroom.

They communicate through JSON strings.

I understand the following example is unsafe, but I am only interested if this is an efficient way of communication.

```
// The Client connects to the server.
// The Client sends a JSON string with the following variables to the server:
   --> Intention: "Request"
   --> Context: "Login"
   --> Message: "username:admin|password:123"
// The Server receives the JSON string and the string goes through an if-statement:
   --> if(Intention.Equals("Request")){...}else if(Intention.Equals("Response")){...}
// The Server now knows it's a Request and moves on to the next step.
   --> if(Context.Equals("Login")){.<check if user exists in server database and if the login details match>.}
// If the login details are correct, The Server marks the connected Client as logged in and sends a JSON string back to The Client:
   --> Intention: "Response"
   --> Context: "Login"
   --> Message: "OK"
// The Client receives the messages and sees it's OK, now the Client shows the user control panel and chatbox to the user which all send other Request JSON strings to The Server.
// Any other context than "Login" check if the Client actually is marked as logged in, if not, the server returns a response with "ERR_NOT_LOGGED_IN"
```

Now I have a few questions:

1. Would this be an efficient/good way of communicating back and forth between Client and Server?
2. What is good/bad about it?
3. Do you have any tips on how to make the communication better/more efficient (content-wise)?
4. If this happened to be a big companies' chat server and passwords weren't stored in plain text but worked with private&public keys, what else would be a big security flaw?

I am asking, because I find a lot about good *ways* for Clients and Servers to communicate, but not about the actual *content* being sent back and forth.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As you said, this is not very safe. some MITM could hack the connection, send it's owm commands. so to make this safe, you should try to make some symetric/asymetric encryption to protect the content and use check sums to avoid faked message

To answer your questions:

1. JSON has fewer overhead than XML, but JSON itselfe is not intened to be used as a communication protocoll. JSON is normally used to persiste some data i.e. configs, in games,... Some messengers use them too (at least the APIs)
2. About what? The good thing is, that there are some little steps to a own protocoll (communication). Bad: What you transmit is bare text (no encryption, no check sums). You can use this for some sort of LAN chat
3. Make your own protocoll, transmit it via Tcp, compress the stream using gzip
4. Just encryped doesn't help you. to proof that this recieved message is from your chat partner and not from a MITM, you have to calculate a checksum, append it, encrypt it and send it. Just read something about the private encryption